# Tab link from Salesforce community not redirecting user to login

Tags: community

The below url takes me to `Login` page.

> https://mydomain-developer-edition.na30.force.com/CommunityName

But the below url is taking to `Under Construction` instead of `Login`. Why?

> https://mydomain-developer-edition.na30.force.com/CommunityName/s/recordlist/CustomObjectAPIName/00B36000004Tnd7EAC?so=00D36000000aUuM

Comment: I think, you have set the home page of Community to `Under Construction` page.  Check the setting there.
However from where you are getting this link.

Comment: Hi Ankuli, When I am logged in and try to open the link, it is not redirecting me to under construction. The link is custom object's tab.

Comment: Do you have the right permission to the Tab's Object .

Comment: Yes. I have permission on the object. When I am logged in, I am able to view that tab. When I put that link and try to go that link without logging in, it is not working.

Comment: why are you opening that link without login. If you want to open without login, you have to give right permission for community guest profile.

Comment: We have an external site which has a link with this. When the user clicks the link from the external site, it should allow the user to login so that it will automatically takes the user to the tab link.

Comment: check the answer now. I got your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I will take a guess - do you have an authenticated session id stored in your browser cookies ? Perhaps you have been testing, logged in at some point, and then tried that second page.

Clear your browser cookies - at least the ones used by salesforce - and then try again.

Comment: Hi CloudHugger, I tried by clearing the cookies. No luck. In Salesforce, if we open a record link, it will redirect us to login page and then redirect us to the record link after login. But in Community, it is not happening.

Comment: Hi All,
I fixed the issue by mapping CommunityLogin page in Authorization Required Page (401) under Site detail.

Previously it was mapped to Under Construction page.

Thank you all for your answers. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Lol thats an easy fix! Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the community default login page to `Under Construction` page. Just make it default.

[image: Reach here at community setting][image: it should be like this]

Comment: Hi, I have double checked. Login page is set as Default Page only. I haven't mapped Under Construction page anywhere.